# Is it possible to connect webservice programatically in ADF mobile 11.1.2.4?

Tags: web-services, mobile, oracle-adf

I want to call some Web Services/REST services which has different URL which cannot been known during design time but known as they are in same structure. URL addresses could be obtain at run time.

I'm curious about is it possible to use web method such as that method with ADF mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can change this with a programmatic way but :
https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/adf_mobile_configuration_service_usage

Or at design time:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/updating_adf_web_service_data